# Why does this code stop working when I put it in a function?

Tags: python, function, pygame

I'm only starting to grasp this idea of abstracting complex stuff via functions, so I decided to practice it a bit in Pygame.

So, this code right here works just fine, the pygame window is present, and you can close it by pressing X button:

```
#pygame initialization code and etc.

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    #code for drawing stuff out
```

But let's say I want to make a function to just handle closing the window just for the sake of it:

```
#pygame initialization code and etc.

running = True

def handle_quit_event():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            return False
        else:
            return True


while running:
    running = handle_quit_event()

    #code for drawing stuff out
```

Now it doesn't work the same way anymore, the pygame window appears for a blink moment, and then program finishes, leaving me with this unease feeling that my idea of abstracting stuff  using functions is all wrong.

[EDIT]: So in my code the function checks for only the first event in the list, but it still doesn't explain why the program finishes right after running it, because even if it checks for the first event, it still should return true by running else clause. So what am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, and show enough code that someone else can copy and paste both versions and see the same behaviour. But as a quick check: did you try running the program from an already-opened terminal window, so that you can see any `print` messages and/or exception traces? If so, what actually happens when you run the program? For example, does it crash with an exception? If so, [show a complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146).

Comment: But first, you should [try to diagnose the problem yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). The most obvious effect of moving the code into a function like this is that, since the `for event in pygame.event.get():` has moved, `event` won't be defined within the main loop, and there won't be an inner loop over the events. Do you expect this to cause a problem for your program's logic? Why or why not?

Comment: "Why I can put some code into functions without breaking the intended behavior, and some apparently not?" Because you are not yet fully accustomed to designing things properly. The solution is to practice more - ideally, with plain command-line programs first, so that you don't have to worry about the complexity introduced by GUI programming, events etc.

Comment: I did run this through cmd just now, and there were no errors or anything like that, just the usual "pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.2) Hello from the pygame community." lines. I also added "print(running)" in a while loop just before calling a function, which gave me the usual pygame introduction lines and two "True" lines. Feeling quite puzzled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstracting functionality into functions is a great idea! Unfortunately your re-write has introduced a bug that *might* be causing your broken game. Without a stacktrace or error messages, it's hard to say exactly why the game is broken.

Onto the bug:

The function `handle_quit_event` doesn't iterate through all the events in `pygame.event.get()`. It returns `True` or `False` after checking the first event.

You probably wanted to write it more like:

```
def handle_quit_event():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            return False
    return True
```

A more pythonic approach that uses list-comprehension and `any()`:

```
def handle_quit_event():
    return not any([event.type == pygame.QUIT for event in pygame.event.get()])
```

Note the flipped logic with `not` is required because your function is currently returning `True` if there is *not* a QUIT event.

Comment: "Without a stacktrace or error messages, it's hard to say exactly why the game is broken." I agree, which is why I did not try to write an answer. You should not, either. Please see [answer]. You have over 50 reputation now, which qualifies you to use the comments under a question to request this kind of additional information.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I disagree. The problem in the OP is obvious, as is the solution. "It's hard to say why the game is broken" is wrong -- it's easy to say why.

Comment: But even then, if my code checks only the first event (and now I can see why, finally), doesn't it still return true? First event in the list isn't of type quit, so it runs else clause, no? If so, the program shouldn't close immediately after running it, but in my case it does. I just don't get it.

Comment: @Dowlgrett, think what happens if there aren't any events in the queue, so the `for` loop executes zero times.  What is the return value in that case?